# Why does my mobile data work for some things?

Tags: samsung, mobile-data, google-play-services, t-mobile

I'm not really sure when this started but I've discovered that I have some type of data. My parents haven't included data in my line yet I'm able to receive notifications from discord, youtube, google feeds etc. I can even do google searches or search for apps on the play store. But I cant actually go on a website or install an app. I cant watch youtube videos or read my discord messages. I cant play online games like brawl stars because it wont connect to the server. I can also use google maps and read reviews. My service provider is tmobile btw. Why does my mobile data work for certain things but not others?

Comment: Your data seems to work only for Google apps.

Comment: @IrfanLatif the Discord seems to be the odd one out though

Comment: Did you try using VPN? If it works then the problem is with your ISP

Comment: Also, while internet providers can certainly block requests to certain sites/IP addresses, I think it's quicker to call T-Mobile's customer support to get the answer because we can't be sure, unless the phone is under the supervision of other apps (e.g. parental filter, etc.)

Comment: It works with bing search and quora motifs too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/Brawlstars/comments/ade4n5/playing_on_mobile_datalte) is same as yours. t mobile.. no brawl stars.. The problem is with your ISP.
I suggest you to try using a trusted local vpn (check if local one works.. not sure). It won't slow down you internet speed and get the job done too.. I too play brawl stars btw :)